# Ηοw can I generate larger than the default images of chord diagrams using Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to use Lilypond to generate (guitar) chord diagrams.

```
\include "lilypond-book-preamble.ly"
\version "2.16.2"

\markup {
  \vspace #1 
  \sans 
  \abs-fontsize #8 
  C   
}

\markup {
  \fret-diagram-terse #"x;3;2;o;1;o;"
}
```

Unfortunately the generated PNG is pretty small, just 121*133 px:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to make them like 500 px high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that all that you really want is to render with a higher number of pixels.  LilyPond renders its PNG images by default at a comparatively low resolution of 101dpi.

It sounds like calling `lilypond` with the `-dresolution=400` option should do the trick for your problem.  Note that LilyPond itself has various vector-class output options, like PostScript, PDF, or SVG.  Using any of those should represent the output using B-splines, so you can use whatever tools you want on the corresponding output files to get bitmaps at arbitrary resolution.  Which is pretty much what happens when using `--png` and `-dresolution=...` options.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the size of the chord diagram using the `override` command like this:

```
\markup {
  \override #'(size . 2.0) {
    \fret-diagram-terse #"x;3;2;o;1;o;"
  }
}
```

This will mess up the layout if you apply this to the example code, but it shows how you can tackle the problem.

I found the code to do this [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/snippets/tweaks-and-overrides_003a-customizing-markup-fret-diagrams).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to take the encapsulated postscript (`.eps`) file generated by lilypond, and render it to PNG at the resolution/size you desire, as indicated in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583821/how-to-convert-a-eps-file-to-a-high-quality-1024x1024-jpg).

The 2.19 version has (some) control of the size of the chord diagrams ([documentation here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-fretted-strings#fret-diagram-markups), I'm not sure when this feature was introduced), however using

```
\markup {
    \fret-diagram-terse #"s:2.0;x;3;2;o;1;o;"
}
```

in your test doesn't affect the size of the resulting png very much.

Comment: Just for the record, it could be done like so: convert -density 2000% *.pdf -resize x500 -background white -alpha remove -strip -quality 100 -set filename:f '%t' '%[filename:f].png'